Is there a way to detect both mouse, keyboard events in the same java class?
Is there a way to detect both mouse, keyboard events in the same java  class?
I failed in putting them in same class. I want a simple short solution showing the transfer of control to any one from  mouse, mouse motion and keyboard event, not lengthy code to this problem.
